# parseFloat() returns NAN for JSON input

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsefloat

I have the following JSON request. I am using bodyParser.json() and express. I need to use this request data into the logic of /get.

```
{
    "type": "A",
    "longitude": "23",
    "latitude": "40"
}
```

and I am trying to parse the longitude and latitude in nodejs. Below is my piece of code

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.get('/api/second', function(request, response) {
    var locationType = request.body.type;
    var longitude = parseFloat(request.body.longitude);
    var latitude =  parseFloat(request.body.latitude);
```

When I am doing console log it is showing me NAN, which should come if the input cant be parsed, but here they are digits. I have tried parseInt in some other code and it worked fine for me.
I am also trying to add 10 to both the variables like this but since longitude itself isnt working I cant proceed further.

```
    var longHigh = longitude+parseFloat('10');
```

Comment: Can't reproduce, `parseFloat('23')` results in `23`

Comment: What is `app`, and what is `response.body` and `typeof(response.body)`?

Comment: *I have the following JSON request* <-- Don't you mean JSON **response**? And, if so, use `JSON.parse()` to turn the response into an object so you don't need to parse out the value.

Comment: You are calling get method.. But `POST` would have req.body.

Comment: I am using express, so app is that.

Comment: I see. Do you have `app.use(bodyParser.json())` or similar? (Or, to ask it another way, is there anything converting `body` to object, or is it still a string?)

Comment: edited, i have bodyParser in place.

Comment: Did u tried with `app.POST`???

Comment: seems like issue with the response you got from api, did you try `console.log(request.body.longitude)`?

Comment: Thanks I understood the mistake as it threw undefined.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine when I try it, so I can only guess that you are missing the appropriate values in `request.body`. Check that the values for `request.body.longitude` and `request.body.latitude` are your expected values.

Use `app.post(...)` instead of `app.get(...)`.
Example is shown below:

*index.js*

```
const app = require("express")();
const morgan = require("morgan");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
// app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // if using urlencoded format
app.post("/api/second", (req, res) => {
  return res.send({
    longitude: parseFloat(req.body.longitude),
    latitude: parseFloat(req.body.latitude),
  });
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Listening on :3000"));
```

Request `Content-Type: application/json`

```
{
    "longitude": "30.2",
    "latitude": "21.4"
}
```

Response I get

```
{
    "longitude": 30.2,
    "latitude": 21.4
}
```